# Regex To Break String Apart By Capitalzation

Tags: php, regex

So I have a regex that breaks a string apart that assumes camelCase or PascalCase and converts it into lowercase_with_underscores.  That regex looks like this (php):

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/(?!^)[[:upper:]]/','_\0', $string));
```

I want to modify this so that it will be able to also break up the string where it assume a string of capitalizes in a row as one unit.  For example, I would to be able to break up the following strings:

```
'GUID' => 'guid'
'SOME_VALUES' => 'some_value'
'someThingELSE' => 'some_thing_else'
```

Any suggestions on how to modify the regex to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$result = strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $string));
```

Comment: How does that take care of something like `THISisODD`

Comment: @luastoned: it will be all lowercase (ie `thisisodd`) like `GUID` -> `guid`

Comment: Not really: `thisis_odd` - It would get `someThingELSE` right though.

Comment: @luastoned: Yes, you're right, but OP didn't say what he really want in this case.

Comment: This does what I am looking for, at least the use cases I am worried about at this time.  I am sure if I need to incorporate more use cases that this regex does not work with, I'll have to update the regex (about ask another question here).